# Azure ADF Expression to generate random string

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

On an Azure dataflow to copy the data from source to sink, both being Azure Managed Instances, I need to generate a unique String starting with PT followed by 7 characters for each row of data.

I am using the below expression to generate it, but it appends the same character rather than random characters. I am missing something simple, but I I can't figure it out. Any help with this is highly appreciated.

```
concat('PT', substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) + substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) + substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) + substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) + substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) + substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) + substring('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789', toInteger(random(1) * length('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTUVWXYZ23456789')), 1) )
```

What I get is strings like 'PTWWWWWWW' , 'PTAAAAAAA', 'PT4444444'

What I expect is string like 'PTFNJH987', 'PT4352BFS', 'PTAWERP3F'

Answer (score 0):

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

**In Azure dataflow there is not a function that returns the random value from range and the expression you are using to get random character from string is every time generating same value because of it you are getting same character repeatedly.**

There is `uuid()` Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) function in Azure dataflow that create unique id with expression

```json
'PT' + upper(right(uuid(),7))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I however want to ignore confusing characters like 0 and O. Thats why I need to select it from that list.

Comment: you can replace those characters with some other characters, symbol or special characters. using replace function.

Comment: They need to be unique though